# How can I access a TextView in the onCreate function?

Tags: java, android

Hi have been using fragments and have a drawer header which is going to display the currently logged in user.

```
activity_main.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the code that creates the layout and the adds the header and menu to the navigation view. I am trying to access the text stored in the drawer header with an id.

The problem i get is that when it tries to set the variable usernameHeader to the id "user" it throws an error saying that there is a null object reference. My understanding is that the drawer is create during the onCreate when it says "actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);" i could be wrong and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I have rewritten and minimal example to show the exact part where it breaks.
I have added the drawer_header.xml which contains the TextView with the id 'user'. I have also added the minimal version of the MainActivity.

```
drawer_header.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_700">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:text="@string/user"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
MainActivity.java
    
    package com.secureit.drawerfragment;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
    
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
        Toolbar toolbar;
        NavigationView navigationView;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    
            actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.user); // This is where the error shows "Null object reference"
            textView.setText("user");
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see any View with id "user" in the xml you provided. So since you get a NPE I suppose that there is no View with id "user" in activity_main.xml or in one of the layout files which are referenced in the  `<include>` tags.

Comment: I would recommend trying to narrow down your problem in the code to a specific part, and then provide us with a [mre]. This will help you get more answers so we can hopefully help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are accessing a TextView in different view from your activity. You should inflate your header view first and then use that to access your TextView. Add this to your onCreate method.

```
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView txtUser= headerView.findViewById(R.id.user);
txtUser.setText("user");
```

Comment: Thank you so much this has fixed my issue.